# Can you tell how big a body of water is by running a current through it?

Tags: electricity, water, measurements, volume

Imagine I have 2 metal cups of water. One is full and one is 10% full. Could I tell how much water is in the cups by attaching a circuit to the outside of each cup individually and getting a resistance or conductivity of each? Would the fuller one be more conductive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not realistically, no.

Water doesn't conduct electricity until you reach voltages high enough to convert the molecules into ions.

So, at low voltages, measured conductivity will only depend on the composition of the cups themselves.

At higher voltages, any current contribution by the water will be completely swamped by the current flowing through the cups.

On the other hand, measuring capacitance may help due to changes in the effective capacitance of the cup as it is filled with water.

It's stretching your problem definition, but you could attach one electrode to the cup and have another one dangling in the center of the cup.

The cup could then act as a capacitor with water and air acting as the dielectric. You could then measure the capacitance and use that to determine how full the cup is. I doubt you could derive values mathematically, but you could calibrate a meter or, if you just need to determine which is full and which is empty, compare the values and base your assessment on that